# simple snr db to linear conversio

Tags: matlab

In  a matlab demo code the following was mentioned

```
SNR = 10^(SNRdB/20); % Calculate linear noise gain
```

I am confused, shouldn't it be

```
SNR = 10^(SNRdB/10); % Calculate linear noise gain
```

Comment: sure this formula should read SNR = 10^(SNRdB/10);. The following two lines in the code dissolve any doubts. Please notify mathworks.com of your finding. As a minimum, you can use a widget "How useful was this information?" at the page bottom. Select one star, click next (>) and write the text message.

Comment: This web page describes the confusion between the two formulas. Both are correct depending on the application. https://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/decibel-conversion-factor-10-or-factor-20.html

Comment: The line `SNR = 10^(SNRdB/20); % Calculate linear noise gain` is from the MATLAB example *Deep Learning Data Synthesis for 5G Channel Estimation* (https://www.mathworks.com/help/5g/ug/deep-learning-data-synthesis-for-5g-channel-estimation.html). Both the code and the comment of this line are wrong: the variable SNR is used in the next lines        `N0 = 1/(sqrt(2.0*nRxAnts*double(waveformInfo.Nfft))*SNR);        noise = N0*complex(randn(size(rxWaveform)),randn(size(rxWaveform)));` making it clear that variable SNR of this demo code is **Psig/Pnoise** and not **Asig/Anoise**

Answer (score -1):

This code is correct, just the variable naming is off:

```
SNR = 10^(SNRdB/20); % Calculate linear noise gain
```

Note that it says *gain*: This is what they intend to multiply with something, for example:

```
noise = SNR * randn(size(clean_normalized_power_signal))
receive_signal = clean_normalized_power_signal + noise
```

As `randn` yields values with a variance of 1, `SNR * randn` yields values with a variance of `SNR`².

Comment: If SNRdB is 80 dB, then SNR will be 10^4 and you then mulitply the noise by this 10^4 factor ? Shouldn't you divide the noise by 10^4 instead?

Comment: no, I don't see why you would. (your whole statement makes no sense)

Comment: Signal-to-noise ratio. The "power" of the signal should be 10^4 greater than the noise variance, no?

Comment: under what circumstances? If you say "the SNR in dB is 80 dB", then the power of the signal (no quotation marks appropriate) is 10⁸ times larger than the variance (and thus, the power) of noise. That's the definition of decibel.

Comment: The OP's code looks like it's taken from a simple example to explain how to convert from dB to linear.   It looks like the gain is meant to divide the noise and that the signal power is 1.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/5g/ug/deep-learning-data-synthesis-for-5g-channel-estimation.html

They divide by the "gain" in the Matlab example N0 = 1/sqrt(2.0*simParameters.NRxAnts*double(waveformInfo.Nfft)*SNR);